# How to get title of a citation?

Tags: biblatex, citing

Is there some way to get the title of a citation shown in the normal text instead of the key? I need the titles of some papers I cite in the normal text, so typing them by hand seems to be superfluous if I already have them in my bibtex file.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @lockstep: Why did you add biblatex to the tags?  The question does not mention Biblatex, only the accepted answer.

Comment: @Charles: See [this](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/577/adding-tags-to-a-question-in-accordance-with-a-provided-answer) discussion in meta. Often, biblatex provides solutions to "general" problems regarding bibliographies/citations.

Comment: @lockstep: Ah, yes, I remember that discussion now, and you are following your own crystal clear policy.  It seems a little odd to me in this case, but Meta is the right place to discuss that.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[`biblatex` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex?lang=en) provides `\citetitle` command for this. You'd better read [the manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and examples of this huge package.

A simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.bib}
@Book{Knuth:ct-a,
  author =       "Donald E. Knuth",
  title =        "The {\TeX}book",
  publisher =    "Addison-Wesley",
  year =         "1986",
  volume =       "A",
  series =       "Computers and Typesetting",
  pages =        "ix + 483",
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\bibliography{foo}
\begin{document}

\citetitle{Knuth:ct-a}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Biblatex link is broken

Answer (score 18):

The `\citetitle` in biblatex prints also markup, if you just way the raw title printed use `\citefield`:

```
\citefield{my-referenc}{title}
```

Comment: How to get the citation as well, e.g., title [4].

Comment: What do you mean by "markup?"

Comment: If we want markup, is there a way to `citefield` *with* markup?

Comment: @RaffiKhatchadourian If I remember correctly `\citetitle` prints the title with markup, e.g. title in cursive.

Comment: Thanks, @ziima. Yes, but I think my question was regarding general fields, not just titles.

Comment: Is there a way to add links to `\citetitle` to reference bibligraph?

Comment: \citefield also works perfect if you want to get the type of a standard, e. g. an ISO standard