# biblatex: why does @mvbook not work as a containter (like @set)?

Tags: biblatex

Working a lot with `@set` containters recently I stumbled across this question: why do entrytypes like `@mvbook` not accept `entryset = {...}` like `@set`? For me that would make sense - one bibliogrphy entry working as a container with one volume after another like `@set`, something like the examples in [additional fields for biblatex/biber “set”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459759/additional-fields-for-biblatex-biber-set) but with the option to provide extended data...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering the *why* conclusively is probably not possible without asking Philipp Lehman, but here are some thoughts.

For the standard styles `@mvbook`/`@mvcollection` is essentially the same as `@book`/`@collection`. The idea behind `@mvbook`/`@mvcollection` would be that it can be used as an 'umbrella entry' for multi-volume works if it makes sense to mention the entire work in the bibliography and not each constituent separately. If one refers to multi-volume reference works like the Encyclopedia Britannica regularly it might be useful to just cite the entire work once and not have to add each volume to the bibliography separately. Once can then use the `\volcite` command to cite a specific volume of the `@mvbook`/`@mvcollection`. Note that usually the data of the `@mv...` entry itself does not refer to its constituent 'child' volumes. These entry types were introduced in `biblatex` v1.2 together with an enhanced data inheritance scheme.

`@set` entries are a concept of some numeric citation styles (I believe mainly from chemistry and physics) that allows to combine several references into one parent reference, since it is assumed that those references are either always cited together or are related in such a way that it makes sense to keep them together in not only the citation, but also a bibliography entry. The `@set` concept does not assume additional relations between the data of the set entries and has no way to deal with special relationship between child entry data (for example with cases where all entries have the same set of authors). `biblatex` just incorporated functionalities of the [`mcite` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/mcite) here. The specific behaviour of `@set` and its `entryset` field is hard-coded in Biber and can not be changed with datamodel macros from `biblatex`.

At the moment types other than `@set` are not set up to consume an `entryset` field and work analogous to `@set` – I assume mainly because no one asked for that to happen until now. The entire framework is not set up to deal with `entryset` for arbitrary entry types: Presumably those children could not be just processed with the full bibliography driver for each entry, instead a very intricate handling of certain parent-child relations would have to be implemented. There is something that *almost* does this, but not quite.

In version 2.0 `biblatex` added the `related` functionality that can be used to describe certain types of relations between bibliography entries. Usually these relations are implemented in such a way that one 'parent' entry has `related` entries, that are then shown together with the parent entry. Usually `related` entries do not appear in the bibliography in their own right, they can't be cited (if they can be cited, they appear in the bibliography separately from their parent). With very little work `related` does almost everything you want, except for the set citations. Since the related children can't be cited themselves, you have to use `\volcite`.

Your [additional fields for biblatex/biber "set"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459759/35864) from could then look like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[doi=false,backend=biber,subentry,sorting=nyt,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}


\renewbibmacro*{related:multivolume}[1]{%
  \entrydata*{#1}{%
    \printtext{%
      \printfield{volume}%
      \printfield{part}}%
    \setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{title}%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnamesequal{author}{savedauthor}}
      or
      test {\ifnameundef{author}}
    }
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{author}{author}%
       \setunit{\addspace}%
       \printnames[byauthor]{author}
       \newunit\newblock}%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnamesequal{editor}{savededitor}}
      or
      test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
    }
      {}
      {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
       \newunit\newblock}%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iflistsequal{location}{savedlocation}}
      or
      test {\iflistundef{location}}
    }
      {}
      {\printlist{location}}%<- typo
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\iflistsequal{publisher}{savedpublisher}}
      or
      test {\iflistundef{publisher}}
    }
      {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
      {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}%
       \printlist{publisher}%
       \setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
  \printdate%
  \newunit\newblock
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\iffieldsequal{isbn}{savedisbn}}
    or
    not togl {bbx:isbn}
  }
    {}
    {\printfield{isbn}}}}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{A,
  author      = {René Goscinny and Albert Uderzo},
  sorttitle   = {Asterix und Obelix 00},
  sortyear    = {1959},
  maintitle   = {Asterix und Obelix},
  location    = {Paris},
  related     = {A:V1,A:V2,A:V3,A:V4,A:V5},
  relatedtype = {multivolume},
}
@Book{A:V1,
  crossref    = {A},
  volume      = {1},
  title       = {Asterix der Gallier},
  sorttitle   = {Asterix und Obelix 01},
  year        = {1959},
  publisher   = {Dargaud},
  options     = {dataonly},
}
@Book{A:V2,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Asterix und Kleopatra},
  volume      = {2},
  sorttitle   = {Asterix und Obelix 02},
  year        = {1968},
  publisher   = {Dargaud},
  options     = {dataonly},
}
@Book{A:V3,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Asterix als Gladiator},
  volume      = {3},
  sorttitle   = {Asterix und Obelix 03},
  year        = {1969},
  publisher   = {Dargaud},
  options     = {dataonly},
}
@Book{A:V4,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Der Kampf der Häuptlinge},
  volume      = {4},
  msorttitle  = {Asterix und Obelix 04},
  year        = {1969},
  publisher   = {Dargaud},
  options     = {dataonly},
}
@Book{A:V5,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Die goldene Sichel},
  volume      = {5},
  sorttitle   = {Asterix und Obelix 05},
  year        = {1970},
  publisher   = {Ehapa-Verlag},
  options     = {dataonly},
}
@Book{A:VX,
  crossref    = {A},
  title       = {Tour de France},
  volume      = {6},
  sorttitle   = {Asterix und Obelix 06},
  year        = {1970},
  publisher   = {Ehapa-Verlag},
  location    = {Berlin},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\volcite{1}{A}

\cite{A,A:VX}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citations only show as "1", "2" or "1, vol. 1". The bibliography looks almost as desired.]

Comment: +1 for *Astérix et Obélix*

Comment: @DG' Not my idea, unfortunately. All credits for that go to the OP's MWE from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459759/35864 (edited the answer to clarify).

Comment: I see. So it's just a good answer...

Comment: @DG' Sorry to disappoint you ;-)

Comment: I will, eventually, get over it. Or, at least, hope, to do so ;)

Comment: I assume you decided to give Sigfridsson a good Sunday rest today.  ;-)

Comment: @moewe Arrrg! **The Romans are crazy!!!** I spent days and have about 500 lines of code for half the job and you handle it with - what? 67? 67??? 67!!!!! Arrrg! I have to go over that one but that looks as promising as christmas and easter on the same day...

Comment: @AndiW Well, this does not do everything exactly the way `@set` does it (and you might have had in mind), but it might just be enough for your actual purposes. I have added an extended, but naturally much more complicated idea in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/462860/35864. There are probably a few downsides to this, but maybe that can be worked around.

Comment: @moewe give me some days to understand your genious, master... :) I'll answer...