# subitems in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I need a simple tool to make and cite subitems in {thebibliography}, something like:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{foo} foo
    \subitem{fooa} bar
    \subitem{foob} lorem
\end{thebibliography}
```

And after compiling I want it too look like:

```
[1] foo
    a) bar
    b) lorem
```

And when citing like

```
\cite{foo}
\cite{foob}
\cite{fooa, foob}
```

It'll produce something like:

```
[1]
[1b]
[1a, b]
```

How can I do it and what packages I'd need to achieve this?

Comment: The `entry sets` from the `biblatex` package provide a similar functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small exampleof how one can use entry sets of `biblatex` in order to get the following output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sortcites=true,
            citestyle=numeric-comp,
            subentry=true,
            ]{biblatex}
            
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{First,
author = {First, A.},
journal = {Journal},
pages = {1762--1776},
volume = {27},
year = {2017}
}
@article{Second,
author = {Second, B.},
journal = {Journal},
pages = {1762--1776},
volume = {27},
year = {2017}
}
@article{Third,
author = {Third, C.},
journal = {Journal},
pages = {1762--1776},
volume = {27},
year = {2017}
}
@article{Fourth,
author = {Fourth, D.},
journal = {Journal},
pages = {1762--1776},
volume = {27},
year = {2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\defbibentryset{set}{First,Second, Third}

\begin{document}

Full entry set: \cite{set}

Individual entries of the set: \cite{First} \cite{Second} \cite{Third}

multiple entries of the entry set: \cite{First,Second}

Entry that is not part of the set: \cite{Fourth}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks nice, thanks. But is there a possibility to include a "main" item in a set, like [1] book a) chapter 1 b) chapter 6?

Comment: @TymoteuszBasak Yes, but it is ... complicated, see for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/459759/35864

Comment: @moewe, indeed, quite complex. Maybe I'll eventually dive into it, but for now, I'll stick with the easier, though less neat solution. Thanks a lot!