# Combine \citetitle{} from biblatex with apacite

Tags: biblatex, citing, apacite

**Is there an option to cite the title from my bibliography with `apacite`?**

I found the question [How to get title of a citation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10610/how-to-get-title-of-a-citation) which is the exact question I had in mind but it did not work with `apacite`. I receive multiple error messages regarding my citation which are according to `apacite` but not compatible with `biblatex` (I assume).

```
Package biblatex error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid
```

In the mentioned question there were two options proposed, both with `biblatex`:

1. `\citetitle{}`
2. `\citefield{}`

Because I like the format of `apacite` I would not want to switch to `biblatex`. Is there an alternative to cite the title with `apacite`?

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\begin{document}

"Some text"

\bibliography{library}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `apacite` (and other BibTeX-based solutions that don't have their own `\citetitle` equivalent) you can use egreg's [`usebib` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/usebib) and its `\usebibentry{<key>}{<field>}` command

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{usebib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journal      = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  year         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
\end{filecontents}

\bibinput{\jobname}

\begin{document}
Lorem \cite{sigfridsson}

\usebibentry{sigfridsson}{title}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998)//Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments]

---

But there is also an APA style for `biblatex`, [`biblatex-apa`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa), so you could say

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{book}
\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{sigfridsson,
  author       = {Sigfridsson, Emma and Ryde, Ulf},
  title        = {Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the
                  electrostatic potential and moments},
  journal      = {Journal of Computational Chemistry},
  year         = 1998,
  volume       = 19,
  number       = 4,
  pages        = {377-395},
  doi          = {10.1002/(SICI)1096-987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\citetitle{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998)//“Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments”]

Comment: Thank you so much. I especially like your `usebib` package. I did not know of it before but it is quite useful.